# Open Workshared document in Revit Architecture 2014 using Revit API

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, revit

I am new to Revit API. I am trying to open revit documents using Revit API 2014. It works fine for the non-workshared revit files but I am not able to open workshared revit files using API. Can anyone point out if I am using a correct way to open workshared revit files? Below is my code snippet:

```
 Document _docCl = uiapp.Application.OpenDocumentFile(_revitFileToOpen);

 if (_docCl.IsWorkshared)
 {
      _docCl.Close();
      _docCl = null;
      ModelPath mdlPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath(this._revitFileToOpen);
      OpenOptions opts = new OpenOptions();
      opts.DetachFromCentralOption = DetachFromCentralOption.DetachAndDiscardWorksets;

      _docClActive = uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(mdlPath, opts, false); //doesn't work
      //uiapp.Application.OpenDocumentFile(mdlPath, opts);   //doesn't work either
}
else
{
      _docClActive = uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(_revitFileToOpen);
}
```

Below is the portion of Journal Log file which seems relevant:

```
'  0.000032         7:<<<WorksharingLog::getSlog [\\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt] 
' 6:< Additional IP address/name found for host INLTAPPL034: 10.10.87.85  
' 6:< DBG_INFO: Get addresses failed (using getaddrinfo) for central server CBA01-SRV-FS01: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. : line 626 of n:\build\2014_ship_x64_inst_20130308_1515\source\revit\revitdb\permissions\WorksharingLog.cpp. 
' 6:< SLOG  user="amitp" 
' 6:< SLOG  build="20130308_1515(x64)" 
' 6:< SLOG  server=??.??.??.?? "???.com" 
' 6:< SLOG  central="\\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt" 
' 6:< SLOG  local="E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt" 
' 6:< SLOG  timer="pulse-6e549c85.tmp" 
'  2.553593!!!!!!! 6:!!!BIG_GAP LoadSerialize 
' 7:< Threaded version of fileExists is enabled. 2.262 seconds elapsed for threaded fileExists \\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt 
'  2.252302         7:<<<fileExists? 
' 6:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:29:58.408 >Open 
'  0.000237         7:<<<fileExists? 
' 6:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:29:58.408 >Open:Local  "E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt" 
'  0.000223         7:<<<fileExists? 
' 6:< fileSizeOnOpen:89056KB 
 'E 22-Aug-2016 20:29:58.409;   7:< 
 ' [Jrn.BasicFileInfo] Rvt.Attr.Worksharing: Local Rvt.Attr.UserName: amitp Rvt.Attr.CentralModelPath: \\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt Rvt.Attr.RevitBuildVersion: Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014 (Build: 20130308_1515(x64)) Rvt.Attr.LastSavePath: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt Rvt.Attr.ProjectSpark: notProjectSpark Rvt.Attr.LocaleWhenSaved: ENU 
'  0.024759          8:<<<app infos and other global data 
' 7:< File was saved in Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014 (Build: 20130308_1515(x64)) 
'  1.071029           10:<<<updating dependencies in delayed deletion 
'  0.005856           10:<<<getAllNonexistentParents in delayed deletion 
'  0.050896           10:<<<findAppInfoNonexistentParents in delayed deletion 
'  1.128135           9:<<delayed deletion 
'  0.007749           9:<<<forceResetOfElemRecOwnerCache 
'  1.223763          8:<<ADocumentUpgrade::docUpgrade 
'  8.653545       5:<<LoadSerialize/ALL_GAPS   2.559036/TurnOff_GAPs 100% 
'  8.653719      4:<<LoadFromStorage 
' 4:< LPSTORAGE RELEASED: plpRootStg=0x14321818, lpRootStg=0x09778080 
' 4:< DummyStorage destroying DataStorageInterface 0x0000000014790090 
' 4:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014790090 
' 4:< AFTER RELEASE: plpRootStg=0x14321818, lpRootStg=0x00000000 
'  0.010065      4:<<<relinquishAllLocks 
' 3:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:30:02.133 <Open:Local 
'  0.000248      4:<<<fileExists? 
' 3:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:30:02.133 <Open 
'  0.000146      4:<<<fileExists? 
'  0.022058       5:<<<forceResetOfElemRecOwnerCache 
' 5:< Unnecessary nesting;Document\PostLoadDocument.cpp;160;String_Revit_DelayedPropagatoinRegen ;N++E(N); 

' 6:< Element Expansion Statistics: 
' 6:<  0% Opening Plans                    (0) 
' 6:<  0% Opening RC Plans                 (0) 
' 6:<  0% Opening 3d Views                 (0) 
' 6:<  0% Opening Elevations and Sections  (0) 
' 6:<  0% In Regnerate                     (0) 
' 6:<  0% In Autojoin                      (0) 
' 6:<  0% In Overlap Checking              (0) 
' 6:<  0% Reviewing PostedWarnings         (0) 
' 6:<  100% Other                            (1560439) 
' 6:< total bytes expanded: 1560439 
' 6:< ;EES;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100; 
'  0.000330         7:<<<ppg constructor 
'  0.000011         7:<<<updating dependencies in dp 
'  0.000031         7:<<<notifyAppInfosOfDP(0) 
'  0.000002          8:<<<updating dependencies in delayed deletion 
'  0.005908          8:<<<getAllNonexistentParents in delayed deletion 
'  0.063470          8:<<<findAppInfoNonexistentParents in delayed deletion 
'  0.000016          8:<<<notifyAppInfosOfDP(1) 
'  0.069706         7:<<delayed deletion 
'  0.176552        6:<<ADocumentMerge::delayedPropagation 
'  0.000262         7:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000032         7:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
' 7:< ::2:: Delta VM: Avail 8384631 MB, Used 534 MB; RAM: Avail +11 -> 2810 MB, Used +0 -> 612 MB 
'  0.000005          8:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000031           9:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000570         7:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000534/TurnOff_GAPs 17% 
'  0.619823        6:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT; 
'  0.810964       5:<<delayed propagation on open 
'  0.000014       5:<<<updating dependencies on open 
' 5:< ::2:: Delta VM: Avail 8384631 MB, Used 534 MB; RAM: Avail +126 -> 2936 MB, Used 612 MB 
' 5:< Threaded version of fileExists is enabled. 2.559 seconds elapsed for threaded fileExists \\DENHV12P\PROJECTS\TCH-FITZ.338\338.081 East Tower\6 Drawings\Revit Working\__CAD Underlays\KITCHEN BACKGROUND - EXT.dwg 
'  2.557757!!!!!!! 6:!!!BIG_GAP reloadLinkedInstances [5/6] 

' 5:< No Keynote File: R:\TCH-FITZ.338\338.081 East Tower\6 Drawings\Revit Working\IMFM Keynotes User.txt 
' 5:< DBG_INFO: Couldn't obtain time/date stamp for R:\TCH-FITZ.338\338.081 East Tower\6 Drawings\Revit Working\IMFM Keynotes User.txt so that cannot correct file create/access/modify time!, the GetLastError is 6: line 1951 of FileUtil.cpp. 

' 4:< Document save history --> : 
' 4:<   Revit Architecture 2014 2014 (2014.000) : 20140709_2115(x64) 
' 4:<   Revit Architecture 2014 2014 (2014.000) : 20130709_2115(x64) 
' 4:<   Revit 2014 2014 (2014.000) : 20131024_2115(x64) 
' 4:<   Revit Architecture 2014 2014 (2014.000) : 20130308_1515(x64) 
' 4:< Document save history <-- 
'  3.448459      4:<<[Cloud]postLoadDocument 
' 12.119349     3:<<DocumentStorage::onOpenDocument [E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt] 
'H 22-Aug-2016 20:30:05.625;   2:< 
Jrn.Directive "DocSymbol"  _
        , "[AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt]"
' 2:< DBG_INFO: When constructing ElementRecord, elem 0 not found: line 24 of n:\build\2014_ship_x64_inst_20130308_1515\source\revit\revitdb\elemtable\ElementRecord.cpp. 
' 3:< TaskDialog "Doc opened... Document Name : E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt"
'CommonButtons : Close
'DefaultButton : Close 
'H 22-Aug-2016 20:30:07.541;   3:< 
Jrn.Data "TaskDialogResult"  _
        , "Doc opened... Document Name : E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt",  _
         "Close", "IDCLOSE"
' 2:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:30:07.710 >WSConfig 
'  1.983669!!!! 3:!!!BIG_GAP [Cloud]handWrittenOpenDocumentFile 
' 2:<  0 ModelServerState "Created": Current server = "Not Queried", Model server = "", Model server state = "Not Applicable" 
' 2:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A46750 
' 3:< MasterLocks 0x000000000012CD70 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface WAS m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A46750 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A46750 
' 3:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A467D0 
' 3:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A46750 
' 3:< MasterLocks 0x000000000012CD70 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A467D0 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A467D0 
' 3:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:30:07.715 .WSConfig:LockRoot  R SCODE=0x80070035 
' 2:< initTransactionStatus unable to refresh permissions 
' 2:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A467D0 
' 2:<  0 ModelServerState "Destroyed": Current server = "Not Queried", Model server = "", Model server state = "Not Applicable" 
' 2:< SLOG $6e549c85 2016-08-22 20:30:07.717 <WSConfig 

' 2:< Element Expansion Statistics: 
' 2:<  0% Opening Plans                    (0) 
' 2:<  0% Opening RC Plans                 (0) 
' 2:<  0% Opening 3d Views                 (0) 
' 2:<  0% Opening Elevations and Sections  (0) 
' 2:<  0% In Regnerate                     (0) 
' 2:<  0% In Autojoin                      (0) 
' 2:<  0% In Overlap Checking              (0) 
' 2:<  13% Reviewing PostedWarnings         (257178) 
' 2:<  87% Other                            (1715892) 
' 2:< total bytes expanded: 1973070 
' 2:< ;EES;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;13;87; 
' 14.282558    2:<<[Cloud]handWrittenOpenDocumentFile/ALL_GAPS   2.163209/TurnOff_GAPs 83% 
' 1:< TaskDialog "Requested document is a workshared document...."
'CommonButtons : Close
'DefaultButton : Close 
'H 22-Aug-2016 20:30:08.872;   1:< 
Jrn.Data "TaskDialogResult"  _
        , "Requested document is a workshared document....",  _
         "Close", "IDCLOSE"
' 1:< INVISIBLE timing block  
' 1:<  0 ModelServerState "Created": Current server = "Not Queried", Model server = "", Model server state = "Not Applicable" 
'  0.000071    2:<<<saveModifiedRvtLinkSymbols 
'  0.000025      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000004      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000003       5:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000014        6:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000292      4:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000275/TurnOff_GAPs 29% 
'  0.129988     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT; 
'  0.000014      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000004      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000002       5:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000011        6:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000270      4:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000257/TurnOff_GAPs 30% 
'  0.002592     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT; 
'  0.000009      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000003      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000002       5:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000006        6:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000174      4:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000167/TurnOff_GAPs 28% 
'  0.001768     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.001581/TurnOff_GAPs 1% 
'  0.000007      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000001      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000001       5:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000005        6:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000156      4:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000150/TurnOff_GAPs 31% 
'  0.001319     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT; 
'  0.000007      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000001      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000001       5:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000006        6:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000162      4:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000155/TurnOff_GAPs 30% 
'  0.001432     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.001262/TurnOff_GAPs 1% 
'  0.000007      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000002      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000001       5:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000005        6:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000150      4:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000144/TurnOff_GAPs 32% 
'  0.001306     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT; 
'  0.140553    2:<<saveModifiedImportSymbols 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A467D0 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A46750 
' 1:< MasterLocks 0x000000000012CEA0 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface WAS m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A46750 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A46750 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A46850 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A46750 
' 1:< MasterLocks 0x000000000012CEA0 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A46850 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A46850 
'  0.000005    2:<<<relinquishAllLocks 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A46850 
'  0.000022     3:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction() -- trackers regen;DOPT; 
'  0.000002     3:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--AtomViewReferencingUpdate();DOPT; 
'  0.000002      4:<<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks--invisible elements;DOPT; 
'  0.000011       5:<<<;PERF;MISC;regenerating 
'  0.000249     3:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction()--end of transaction checks;DOPT;/ALL_GAPS   0.000236/TurnOff_GAPs 32% 
'  0.001897    2:<<EndOrAbortUndoTransaction();DOPT; 
' 2:< MasterLocks 0x00000000574F0080 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface WAS m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A467D0 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A467D0 
' 2:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A46850 
' 2:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A467D0 
' 2:< MasterLocks 0x00000000574F0080 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A46850 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A46850 
' 4:< ::2:: Delta VM: Avail -175 -> 8384455 MB, Used +2 -> 537 MB; RAM: Avail +0 -> 2947 MB, Used +1 -> 615 MB 
' 4:< MasterLocks 0x00000000574F0080 DummyStorage stole m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A46850 but left m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A46850 
' 4:< LPSTORAGE ACQUIRED: DocumentStorage=0x14321750, plpRootStg=0x14321818, lpRootStg=0x09778080 
'  0.003546      4:<<acquireFileLock 
'  0.003637     3:<<acquiring lock 
' 3:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A467D0 
'C 22-Aug-2016 20:30:09.087;   4:< File: Open 
'  0.000002       5:<<<OpenDocumentTask::acquireFileLock 
'  0.030179          8:<<<loadAllClasses 
'  0.000038          8:<<<RegisterPreDocLoadCallback::invokeCallbacks 
'  0.000769           9:<<<LoadModel DSI 
'  0.000833          8:<<loading DocumentStorageIndex 
 'E 22-Aug-2016 20:30:09.119;   8:< 
 ' [Jrn.BasicFileInfo] Rvt.Attr.Worksharing: Local Rvt.Attr.UserName: amitp Rvt.Attr.CentralModelPath: \\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt Rvt.Attr.RevitBuildVersion: Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014 (Build: 20130308_1515(x64)) Rvt.Attr.LastSavePath: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt Rvt.Attr.ProjectSpark: notProjectSpark Rvt.Attr.LocaleWhenSaved: ENU 
'  0.000510           9:<<<History 
'  0.001148           9:<<<increment table 
'  0.015164          8:<<DocumentStorageIndexImpl::loadDocument()  
'  0.047160        6:<<LoadSerialize 
'  0.047289       5:<<LoadFromStorage 
'  0.047553      4:<<DocumentStorage::onOpenDocument [E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt] 
' 3:< compare GUIDs; creation c18fea7b-7fd5-40e0-9b77-3ccb92fe3eeb; detach c2effc75-eec7-4a68-9985-7cb8985cc740; upgrade 80d9c28b-d7e7-4013-8d2d-edd4c21d435a; DIFF prevUpgrade c18fea7b-7fd5-40e0-9b77-3ccb92fe3eeb != 80d9c28b-d7e7-4013-8d2d-edd4c21d435a 
'  0.000004      4:<<<relinquishAllLocks 
' 3:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A467D0 

' 2:< Revit Graphics Information 
' 2:<   Current Mode : DirectX Hardware 
' 2:<   Use Hardware: ON 
' 2:<   Use Overlays : ON 
' 2:< After : Create Display Manager 

'  0.123757    2:<<OpenFileForSave::openFileForSave 
'  0.000002      4:<<<storePreviewImage 
'  0.003901      4:<<<storeValidation 
'  0.064306       5:<<<ElementSender::createDocSaveSwapout 
'  0.000127         7:<<<Reconsolidater::getAllLiveElementCounts 
' 6:< [ISL] Stream#266 (0 live/0 total elements) marked for deletion during reconsolidation 
'  0.000248        6:<<Reconsolidater::getStreamsToReconsolidate 
'  0.000281       5:<<pre-swapout reconsolidate 
'  0.000620       5:<<<ElemTable::updateETforSave 
'  0.000001       5:<<<ElementSender::swapOut()  
' 5:< updateDITforSave increment 267L has 12782 (+0) episodes 
'  0.000358       5:<<Updating increment and partition tables for save (quick) 
'  0.003116        6:<<<Storing increment table  [#obsolete=15, first#=212, last#=267] 
'  0.062210        6:<<<Storing DocumentHistory  [#episodes=12783, #valid=11257, max ep id#=12782] 
'  0.011262        6:<<<Storing PartitionTable  [#partitions=1512, #deleted=815, max id#=43818] 
'  0.001607        6:<<<Storing Content Documents 
'  0.181542        6:<<<Storing ElemTable  [#elts=137923, #graveyard=928, max id#=12483562] 
'  0.035586        6:<<<Storing global stream 
'  0.000048         7:<<<OLEStgLock::commit overwrite=yes consolidate=no 
'  0.304950        6:<<commitAllGlobalStreams/ALL_GAPS   0.304902/TurnOff_GAPs 100% 
'  0.615831       5:<<Storing tables 
'  0.000024          8:<<<OLEStgLock::commit overwrite=yes consolidate=no 
'  0.031170       5:<<ModelStorer::storeStreams() /ALL_GAPS   0.031146/TurnOff_GAPs 99% 
'  0.713105      4:<<ModelStorer::storeDocument()  
' 3:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\OleStorage.cpp(240) despite m_dontFetch 
'  0.000224       5:<<<storeSelf DocumentStorageIndexBackup 
'  0.001857       5:<<<storeSelf updateDSIforSave 
'  0.005144      4:<<DocumentStorageIndex::storeSelf [12781] 
' 3:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET n:\build\2014_ship_x64_inst_20130308_1515\source\revit\revitdb\document\Document.cpp(6024) despite m_dontFetch 
' 3:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\ProjectExtras.cpp(122) despite m_dontFetch 
' 4:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\OleStorage.cpp(240) despite m_dontFetch 
' 4:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\ProjectExtras.cpp(140) despite m_dontFetch 
' 4:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\ProjectExtras.cpp(159) despite m_dontFetch 
'  0.030804      4:<<storeBasicFileInfoStream 
'  0.000007      4:<<<storePartAtomStream 
'  0.168626      4:<<storeProjectXMLInfoStream 
'  1.006264     3:<<TrustedUtility::SaveToStorage - serialize block/ALL_GAPS   0.084674/TurnOff_GAPs 65% 
'  0.032333     3:<<TrustedUtility::SaveToStorage - commit format/contents locks 
' 3:< ::3:: Delta VM: Avail +11 -> 8384467 MB, Used 537 MB; RAM: Avail -14 -> 2933 MB, Used +12 -> 628 MB 
'  0.268941      4:<<<OLEStgLock::commit overwrite=yes consolidate=yes 
'  0.269292     3:<<TrustedUtility::SaveToStorage - commitStorage 
'  1.309396    2:<<TrustedUtility::saveToStorage 
'H 22-Aug-2016 20:30:10.550;   1:< 
Jrn.Directive "DocSymbol"  _
        , "[AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt]"
'  0.000395     3:<<<preCommit finding backup files 
' 2:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\OleStorage.cpp(240) despite m_dontFetch 
'  0.000177     3:<<<findFileAndWorksetVersionsToKeep 
'  0.000387     3:<<<BackupPaths::DocumentVersionIterator 
' 2:< GETLOADSTOREOPTIONS in GET Project\OleStorage.cpp(240) despite m_dontFetch 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\265_0.rws 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\global.7070.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\history.7070.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\elemtable.7070.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\contentdocuments.0431.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\partitiontable.7070.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\incrementtable.7099.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\basicfileinfo.7065.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\transmissiondata.0431.dat 
' 3:< Marking file for quick purge: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL_backup\projectinformation.0431.dat 
'  0.001184     3:<<<findFilesToDeleteBasedOnIncrements 
'  0.003227    2:<<BackupFileManager::preUnlockPreCommit 
'  0.000006    2:<<<BackupFileManager::postUnlockPreCommit 
'  0.013889    2:<<<BackupFileManager::commit 
' 2:< ::3:: Delta VM: Avail +176 -> 8384643 MB, Used 537 MB; RAM: Avail +3 -> 2937 MB, Used -4 -> 624 MB 
' 2:< LPSTORAGE RELEASED: plpRootStg=0x14321818, lpRootStg=0x09778080 
' 2:< DummyStorage destroying DataStorageInterface 0x0000000014A46850 
' 2:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A46850 
' 2:< AFTER RELEASE: plpRootStg=0x14321818, lpRootStg=0x00000000 
'  0.005317    2:<<<relinquishAllLocks 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A46850 
'  0.000004    2:<<<temporaryEffects.destroy(DoSave) 
'  0.000255    2:<<<commit/cleanup 
'  0.000005    2:<<<relinquishAllLocks 
' 1:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A46850 

'C 22-Aug-2016 20:30:11.048;   3:< File: Open 
' 4:< DataStorageInterface created 0x000000001478E590 
' 4:< Connecting session [$404fa1d3] to Worksharing Log [C:\Users\amitp\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014\Journals\journal.0001.txt] 
'  0.000013       5:<<<WorksharingLog::getSlog [] 
' 4:< Additional IP address/name found for host INLTAPPL034: 10.10.87.85  
' 5:< MasterLocks 0x0000000046654730 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface WAS m_oDataStorage 0x000000001478E590 m_pDataStorage 0x000000001478E590 
' 5:< DataStorageInterface created 0x000000001478F510 
' 5:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x000000001478E590 
' 5:< MasterLocks 0x0000000046654730 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface m_oDataStorage 0x000000001478F510 m_pDataStorage 0x000000001478F510 
' 5:< ::4:: Delta VM: Avail -169 -> 8384499 MB, Used 513 MB; RAM: Avail +4 -> 2960 MB, Used 601 MB 
' 5:< MasterLocks 0x0000000046654730 DummyStorage stole m_oDataStorage 0x000000001478F510 but left m_pDataStorage 0x000000001478F510 
' 5:< LPSTORAGE ACQUIRED: DocumentStorage=0x14321ab0, plpRootStg=0x14321b78, lpRootStg=0x14881ba0 
'  0.002869       5:<<acquireFileLock 
'  0.004018      4:<<OpenDocumentTask::acquireFileLock 
'  0.020358         7:<<<loadAllClasses 
'  0.000029         7:<<<RegisterPreDocLoadCallback::invokeCallbacks 
'  0.000506          8:<<<LoadModel DSI 
'  0.000557         7:<<loading DocumentStorageIndex 
 'E 22-Aug-2016 20:30:11.074;   7:< 
 ' [Jrn.BasicFileInfo] Rvt.Attr.Worksharing: Local Rvt.Attr.UserName: amitp Rvt.Attr.CentralModelPath: \\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt Rvt.Attr.RevitBuildVersion: Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014 (Build: 20130308_1515(x64)) Rvt.Attr.LastSavePath: E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt Rvt.Attr.ProjectSpark: notProjectSpark Rvt.Attr.LocaleWhenSaved: ENU 
'  0.057984          8:<<<History 
'  0.001012          8:<<<increment table 
'  0.002487          8:<<<WorksetTable 
'  0.086087         7:<<DocumentStorageIndexImpl::loadDocument()  
'  0.000027          8:<<<distributeKnownEpisodesToSubsets 
'  0.107716       5:<<LoadSerialize 
'  0.107821      4:<<LoadFromStorage 
' 4:< ::5:: Delta VM: Avail +174 -> 8384674 MB, Used 513 MB; RAM: Avail 2960 MB, Used 601 MB 
' 4:< LPSTORAGE RELEASED: plpRootStg=0x14321b78, lpRootStg=0x14881ba0 
' 4:< DummyStorage destroying DataStorageInterface 0x000000001478F510 
' 4:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x000000001478F510 
' 4:< AFTER RELEASE: plpRootStg=0x14321b78, lpRootStg=0x00000000 
'  0.001984      4:<<<relinquishAllLocks 
'  0.114172     3:<<DocumentStorage::onOpenDocument [E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt] 
' 2:< Connecting session [$1de94fdf] to Worksharing Log [C:\Users\amitp\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014\Journals\journal.0001.txt] 
' 2:< Additional IP address/name found for host INLTAPPL034: 10.10.87.85  
' 2:< SLOG $1de94fdf 2016-08-22 20:30:13.425 >Session  $1de94fdf 
' 2:< SLOG  user="amitp" 
' 2:< SLOG  build="20130308_1515(x64)" 
' 2:< SLOG  journal="C:\Users\amitp\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014\Journals\journal.0001.txt" 
' 2:< SLOG  host=fe80::59d8:cab6:ad7:5925%14 "INLTAPPL034.MPTDC1-India.MirrorPlus.com" 
' 2:< SLOG  server=??.??.??.?? "???.com" 
' 2:< SLOG  central="\\CBA01-SRV-FS01\EAD Files\C0190-ARC\15-0091-CHCO-Children's Hospital Colorado\80-CHCO-Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt" 
' 2:< SLOG  local="E:\Test Dataset\Revit Files\AMCFM_C_AI_R14_HL.rvt" 
' 2:< SLOG  timer="pulse-1de94fdf.tmp" 
' 2:< SLOG  timebias=-330 
'  2.251970!!!! 3:!!!BIG_GAP MFCProjectAgent::getWorksetConfigForLoading 'Specify' = askUser 
' 2:< SLOG $1de94fdf 2016-08-22 20:30:13.426 >WSD 
' 3:<  0 ModelServerState "Created": Current server = "Not Queried", Model server = "", Model server state = "Not Applicable" 
' 3:< DataStorageInterface created 0x000000001478E590 
' 4:< MasterLocks 0x000000000012C2F0 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface WAS m_oDataStorage 0x000000001478E590 m_pDataStorage 0x000000001478E590 
' 4:< DataStorageInterface created 0x0000000014A4CD50 
' 4:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x000000001478E590 
' 4:< MasterLocks 0x000000000012C2F0 ensureAppropriateStorage DataStorageInterface m_oDataStorage 0x0000000014A4CD50 m_pDataStorage 0x0000000014A4CD50 
' 4:< SLOG $1de94fdf 2016-08-22 20:30:13.434 .WSD:LockRoot  R SCODE=0x80070035 
' 3:< initTransactionStatus unable to refresh permissions 
' 3:< DataStorageInterface destroyed 0x0000000014A4CD50 
**' 3:<  0 ModelServerState "Destroyed": Current server = "Not Queried", Model server = "", Model server state = "Not Applicable" 
'  2.407079=== 2:<<MFCProjectAgent::getWorksetConfigForLoading 'Specify' = askUser 
' 1:<  System.FormatException exception(Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.) was thrown from a handler of Idling event. The API event handler was registered by application Application RevitCommandListener (acf561d2-8c6c-4beb-be55-2346825b53a4). Changes made by this handler are going to be discarded. 
' 0:< The Idling event callback used 20 seconds
```

Tried below code too,as suggested by @Matt but that is not opening the document either:

```
OpenOptions options = new OpenOptions();
options.DetachFromCentralOption = DetachFromCentralOption.DetachAndDiscardWorksets;
ModelPath mdlPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath(_revitFileToOpen);
uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(mdlPath, options, false);
```

Comment: what's the error message you're receiving?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves: I am not receiving any error messages. Revit shows in it's progress bar that document is opening but it is not opening the document,may be some internal exception.

Comment: Also the Document Opened event is firing for this line: Document _docCl = uiapp.Application.OpenDocumentFile(_revitFileToOpen) but not for _docClActive = uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(mdlPath, opts, false) and revit is neither showing any error msgs nor the document. Any help regarding this?

Comment: please clear the Journal, then run again and check if something relevant appears at the Journal file (see more https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Location-of-journal-files.html)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves : I have edited my question. Please have a look into the journal file.

Comment: Idling event is throwing some Format exception.

Comment: do you have any idling event or any other app on your machine? Can you try disable them for this testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121637/discussion-between-amit-and-augusto-goncalves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - it looks like there's some kind of problem in your code that's related to the worksets, and it's tripping up the idling event callback that you're in.

That said - Opening a whole file just to determine if it is workshared is a very expensive operation. Instead, you can call:

```
BasicFileInfo info = BasicFileInfo.Extract(filename);
if (info.IsWorkshared)...
```

Also - I think it probably would also work to call the OpenAndActivate method with the OpenDetached option, even if the model was not workshared. I believe I've done that before as well.

Comment: Thanks for BasicFileInfo class.I tried opening revit file using call to OpenAndActivate method with the OpenDetached option but that also has the same effect.